# Accessibility:Modifying bootstrap-multiselect dropdown lists to be usable with screen readers

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, bootstrap-multiselect

I am attempting to use the Bootstrap-multiselect plug-in by David Stutz; documentation is located at http://davidstuts.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect
This is a plugin to convert ordinary select drop-downs to use better styling and features such as filtering. However, the output of the plug-in uses mark-up where a radio button is enclosed within an anchor tag. This means that when using a screen reader, the screen reader picks up the anchor tag and ignores the radio button since it is enclosed within the element. I have tried to modify this behaviar to enhance accessibility by removing the anchor tag and replacing it with a span, but the missing anchor causes keyboard accessibility to break.

So i'd like to request help on finding a way where the keyboard and screen reader accessibility can work together using alternative mark-up to the default in the plugin; adding a role of 'radio' did not work either since the screen reader interacts with the anchor and not the enclosed radio button.

Comment: It was awhile. Did you have any solution? I'd be very interested

Answer (score 0):

The most likely way for your "keyboard accessibility to break"  would be if the anchor tags had a tabindex attribute on them. If you replaced one with a span then the radio button inside would be left without that tabindex. That would mean the keyboard tabbing would skip it in the tab order, and leave it until last, after all the other (tabindexed tags) had been done. That's how tabindex works.

If this guess is wide of the mark, then please give us exact information saying what broke and how, what the symptom is. We need that info to see what the problem is.